# illegal argument http host

Tags: java, jsp

Struggling with what should be a simple piece of code (but then I am a newbie)

```
String ipaddrlist = request.getParameter("ipaddrlist");
System.out.println (ipaddrlist);

ReaderDriver art = new ReaderDriver();

String ipaddrs[] = ipaddrlist.split(",");
System.out.println (Arrays.toString(ipaddrs));

for(int i=0; i< ipaddrs.length ; i++)
{
art.setOutputs(ipaddrs[i], false);
}
```

ipaddrlist = ,192.168.150.210
ipaddrs = ,  192.168.150.210  (splits the comma away from the IP address). An array is used because there could be more than one IP address in the list.

But the for(int loop seems to be sending both the correct IP address and also a null which causes a java IllegalArgumentException = http host = null. I cant figure out how to print the for loop to the console so I can see exactly what is being sent.

If I replace the for loop and just use a single fixed IP address then there is no exception.

I dont want to have to set proxies etc if I can avoid it and a catch exception doesn't seem to work.

First 2 lines of the ReaderDriver (but I dont want to have to alter this code if possible, the issue seems to be the for loop sending a null after the real IP address)

```
public boolean setOutputs(String ipAddress, boolean status)
{
String url = (new    StringBuilder()).append("http://").append(ipAddress).append("/UE/rci").toString();
```

I want to stop the for loop sending anything other than IP addreeses (i.e. blank).

Thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Can you also paste code for ReaderDriver  class. As per this code, we won't be able to figure out what is setOutputs API doing.  Rest of the code looks fine. If there is no value before comma then it will be treated as blank.

Comment: Updated original code, but see comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just do simple validation in your code:

```
for(int i=0; i< ipaddrs.length ; i++)
{
  // Or you can validate by your way(for exp: checking url ), here is checking null or empty
  if (ipaddrs[i] != null && !ipaddrs[i].isEmpty())
      art.setOutputs(ipaddrs[i], false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ducanhng (and everyone else who responded), this solved the issue perfectly.

Comment: I thought your program just need a simple way to pass by null or empty when printing the result(have not exception). So here it is and also see my comment if you want to do some other validations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when the value of ipaddress is blank, code will create an invalid URL.

```
http:///UE/rci                 //Invalid URL if ip address is blank
http://192.168.150.210/UE/rci  //Valid URL
```

I am assuming you are using this URL to create connection something like

```
 URL myURL = new URL(url);
 URLConnection myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();
 myURLConnection.connect();
```

You need to validate the URL before opening a connection.

```
        String url = (new    StringBuilder()).append("http://").append(ipaddrs[i]).append("/UE/rci").toString();
        String[] schemes = {"http","https"}; // DEFAULT schemes = "http", "https", "ftp"
        UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator(schemes);
        if (urlValidator.isValid(url)) 
        {
           System.out.println("URL is valid..Continue processing");
           try {
                URL myURL = new URL(url);
                URLConnection myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();
                myURLConnection.connect();
            } 
            catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
                e.printStackTrace();
                // new URL() failed
                // ...
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {   
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        } else {
           System.out.println("URL is invalid");
        }
```

[UrlValidator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.html) class is a part of Apache commons validator jar which can be downloaded from https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/download_validator.cgi

There a two UrlValidator classes. Use org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator because other one is deprecated.

Instead of UrlValidator, you can also add a check in for loop.

```
for(int i=0; i< ipaddrs.length ; i++)
{
    if(ipaddrs[i] !=null && !"".equals(ipaddrs[i].trim()))
    {
        art.setOutputs(ipaddrs[i], false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Leozeo, but can we not just prevent a blank from being sent by the for loop rather than having to add a validator.

Comment: @Active You can skip call to setOutputs API if ipaddress is blank. Check updated code.

Comment: Thanks Leozeo, though your for loop has a syntax error somewhere on the if line (insert Statement to complete block statements)

Comment: @Active just updated the code :) . I hope it will help others too :).

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the trailing comma if it is there.

```
String sanitizedIpAddr = "";
String ipaddrlist = request.getParameter("ipaddrlist");
System.out.println (ipaddrlist);

ReaderDriver art = new ReaderDriver();

if(ipaddrlist.charAt(ipaddrlist.length()-1) == ','){
       sanitizedIpAddr = ipaddrlist.substring(0, ipaddrlist.length()-2);
      }

String ipaddrs[] = sanitizedIpAddr.split(",");
System.out.println (Arrays.toString(ipaddrs));

for(int i=0; i< ipaddrs.length ; i++)
{
art.setOutputs(ipaddrs[i], false);
}
```

Then continue with your regular code.

Comment: Thanks Eduardo, but I now appear to have 2 string arrays to put in the for loop (ipaddrlist and sanitizedIPAddr), not sure how to do this, could you reproduce my original code with your additions in it (a newbie as you can see)

Comment: @Active just replace everything with the new sanitized one. All you're doing is removing the comma at the end if there is one. This should fix your null pointer exception

Comment: Thanks, but this breaks the code (length cannot be resolved and must be an array type)                                                                              for(int i=0; i< sanitizedIpAddr.length ; i++)
    {
       art.setOutputs(sanitizedIpAddr[i], false);
    }

Comment: Try what I just added, length has to be length()